# What is this fruiting shrub found on the banks of a brackish pond on Long Island, NY?

Tags: identification

This shrub is growing in sandy soil along the banks of a brackish pond on Long Island. We did not see others in the area. As you can see, it is adjacent to phragmites, which hints that it could have wet feet for at least part of the year.

The photo was taken early in November - an unusually warm autumn.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like *Callicarpa americana var. lactea* (white American beautyberry) but without leaves it might not be an easy identification.

I've never seen one in person, so I'm not sure how white the berries stay.  We have a number of the purple berry species and all retain their color until the birds pick the bushed clean in early December.

Comment: The way they hold their berries sure is similar.